# Export data from branch.io through API

Tags: python, branch.io

I am using this URL

```
https://api.branch.io/v2/export/XXXXX?branch_secret=XXXXX&export_date=2018-11-18
```

with the required keys but after execution the output comes like:

```
{
   "links_export_url": [],
   "events_export_url": [],
   "clicks_export_url": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Our v2 exports API is actually a legacy feature. I recommend you use our v3 Export API (Must be signed up for data feeds). If you do not have a Data feeds subscription, you can also access these reports through our CSV exports which you can find in the dashboard.

https://dashboard.branch.io/data-import-export/csv-exports